# Exporting a vector logo to JPG/TIFF changes colour values

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, export, cmyk, jpg

I'm facing a perplexing problem while exporting a vector graphic (a logo) from illustrator. The document colour profile is CMYK and I'm attempting to export high resolution JPG/TIFF files for print in CMYK. While doing so, I'm noticing the colour values shift a bit. The colour I want my logo to have is the following:
[image: Actual colour values]

But the output in JPG provides different values when the colour is picked in Photoshop:

[image: JPG Output colour values]

I have no idea why this shift is happening. I've also tried to change the profile to "Don't colour manage this document" from the default "Working CMYK: U.S. Web coated (SWOP) v2" in illustrator. But that doesn't seem to have helped either. What am I doing wrong?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to export a raster format if the destination is print?

Comment: Also realize the eyedropper in Photoshop can *average* pixels in a 3x3 or 5x5 area if it's set to do so -- which I believe is the default.

Comment: Hi @Scott , So the client intends to use the logo in business stationary like presentations, which he prints as handouts for clients. The colour discrepancy is most visible here as it appears a lot brighter.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the why question. `:)` Is your client going to have things commercially printed or merely use the office printer? if using the office printer, is it a color laser printer with a postscript level 3 RIP or merely an inkjet printer? Is he going to print from Microsoft software? Microsoft software has *no clue* what CMYK is. If using an inkjet printer you should give him an RGB file. Inkjets expect to see RGB. They don't understand CMYK unless there's a postscript level 3 RIP, which most inkjets do *not* have. in other words,. your client may be better served by RGB.

Comment: And if using MS software.. an RGB PNG file may be optimum. Unless the logo is a perfect rectangle, the transparency possible with the PNG format will be exceptionally useful to the client. If the client is going to print things with a commercial printer, they should use the vector file, not an exported raster image. Basically, I can think of no use cases where a CMYK JPG or TIFF of a logo are actually worthwhile if a vector file exists.

Comment: @Scott thanks for this. Although I tried a PNG export too but the transparency translates to a black colour. The client is indeed using an office inkjet printer.